# Continuous wavelets transform

Tags: signals, wavelet

I am trying to attempt plot a real, imaginary, phase, and modulus of a wavelets coefficient. The mother wavelets i am using is morlet. Down below is my signal

`dt = 0.001`
`sampling_rate = 1000`
`K = 3`
`t = np.arange(0, 1, dt)                             # Time from 0 to 1s`
`f1 = np.sin(2`*`np.pi`*`50`*`t) + np.sin(2`*`np.pi`*`100`*`t)`*`(t < 0.5)           # From 0 to 0.5s`*
`f2 = np.sin(2np.pi`*`20`*`t) + np.sin(2`*`np.pi`*`100`*`t)`*`(t >= 0.5) + K*(1*(0.8 == t)+1*(0.804 == t)`)
I would like to ask that if what i am trying to do having any buit in function or it is a math problem that i have to write it out myself. I read document for pywt but they dont have any function that can plot real, imaginary or whatever above. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the syntax that you are using. From `t` between 0 and 0.5s, `f1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t)`, but then what happens when `t` is between 0.5 and 1s?

Comment: I think what you need is all in `numpy` and `scipy`, see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.imag.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.morlet2.html -- if you read the documentation of these functions (morlet2 should be used with cwt) you will get a much clearer idea what you need.